# sort array of objects according to month name?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a array of objects with months and i want to sort them in a specific order such as fiscal year format how do i do that?

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{subscribedCustomers: 1, req_count: 1, revenue: 1532.82, getMonth: "April", totalComp: 1}
1:{subscribedCustomers: 0, req_count: 0, revenue: null, getMonth: "June", totalComp: 0}
2:{subscribedCustomers: 1, req_count: 1, revenue: 2948.82, getMonth: "May", totalComp: 1}
3:{getMonth: "July", totalComp: 0}
4:{getMonth: "August", totalComp: 0}
5:{getMonth: "September", totalComp: 0}
6:{getMonth: "October", totalComp: 0}
7:{getMonth: "November", totalComp: 0}
8:{getMonth: "December", totalComp: 0}
9:{getMonth: "January", totalComp: 0}
10:{getMonth: "February", totalComp: 0}
11:{getMonth: "March", totalComp: 0}
```

How do i sort it to months in the following format

[ 
  'April', 
  'May', 
  'June', 
  'July', 
  'August', 
  'September', 
  'October', 
  'November', 
  'December',
  'January', 
  'February', 
  'March'];

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add the attempt to your question including a proper explanation of what (and how it) didn't work. _"wasn't working"_ is useless for us.

Answer (score 3):

not the most performant version, but should do it

```
const refArray = [ 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March'];    
yourArray.sort((a,b) => { return refArray.indexOf(a.getMonth) - refArray.indexOf(b.getMonth)});
```

Comment: Tried it already wasn't working :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Object that maps months to a number and then use the sort function to sort your array according to the Object's values:

```js
let data = [{subscribedCustomers: 1, req_count: 1, revenue: 1532.82, getMonth: "April", totalComp: 1},{subscribedCustomers: 0, req_count: 0, revenue: null, getMonth: "June", totalComp: 0},{subscribedCustomers: 1, req_count: 1, revenue: 2948.82, getMonth: "May", totalComp: 1},{getMonth: "July", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "August", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "September", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "October", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "November", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "December", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "January", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "February", totalComp: 0},{getMonth: "March", totalComp: 0}];

const months = {"January": 1,"February": 2,"March": 3,"April": 4,"May": 5,"June": 6,"July": 7,"August": 8,"September": 9,"October": 10,"November": 11,"December": 12};

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return months[a.getMonth] - months[b.getMonth];
});

console.log(data)
```